# How to unfollow url in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I created this simple code to learn about login and registration in django. My views.py is

```
def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'products':products})


def register(request):
    return render(request,'register.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request,'login.html')

def logout(request):
    return HttpResponse('logout')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('register/', views.register),
    path('login/', views.login),
    path('logout/', views.logout),
]
```

base.html

```
<a href="register">Register</a>
<a href="login/">Login</a>
<h3>Base html </h3>
{% block content %}


{% endblock %}
```

register.html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

<h1>Register</h1>

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

login.html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

<h1>Login</h1>

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

At http://127.0.0.1:8000/ when I click `Register` link it follows to http://127.0.0.1:8000/register page but when I click the 'Register link at that page it follows to http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/register which gives 404 error. How do I unfollow url that is instead of going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/register` it has to  go `http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/`?

Comment: Could you show `index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your base. html you should generally specify a link with `{% url 'register' %}`

So like that:

```
<a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
```

But to use it, in you settings.py you should specify the directory where your templates are stored relative to the base directory of your project

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your/way/to/templates'),
        ],
        ...
]
```

Also `import os.path` at the top of settings.py

**EDIT**

when you specify your urls.py, you should give name to every url.

```
path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
```

so in `<a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>` you call the name of the url

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen your base urls from project side but seems your are doing this way in my guess
you can remove register from base urls of project file

```
path(
        'register/',
        include('register.urls'),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for this problem to name the URLs. Just give them names and refer to that names in the HTML file

My solution:

**urls.py**

```
 urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('register/', views.register,name="register"),
    path('login/', views.login,name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logout,name="logout"),
]
```

**base.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'register'%}">Register</a>
<a href="{% url 'login'%}">Login</a>
<h3>Base html </h3>
```